# Can I attach iSCSI to VMware ESXi without licensing?

Tags: vmware-esxi, iscsi

I have multiple ESXi hosts, managed individually because I have yet to buy licensing.  Can I tie my iSCSI SAN to these hosts and utilize it for VM storage and run VM's on that iSCSI device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, an iSCSI datastore can be added with just the free hypervisor license.

Comment: Sweet, thank you.  Can this be added to more than one hypervisor at once?

Comment: @eth0 - As far as I know, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. This is entirely possible.

The thing you lose by not having licensing is the vCenter management. However, that has no impact on your ability to see datastores (iSCSI or otherwise).